# Мало/ много + что or чего?

Tags: грамматика

What's the difference here? I've seen both

я мало чего помню

я мало что помню

я много чего умею делать

я много что умею делать

я много что/чего видел

When should I use винительный and when родительный падеж?

Comment: A similar question with lots of answers: [Why do Russians say “Чего?” and not “Что?” when they didn't understand something?](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/9141/why-do-russians-say-Чего-and-not-Что-when-they-didnt-understand-something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference, neither in the meaning nor in style. "Чего" sounds a little bit more colloquial though and is used more often.

Answer (score 1):

It is about the same as the difference between «*я что-то помню*» and «*я чего-то помню*», or as the difference between «*я кое-что говорил*» and «*я кое-чего говорил*». In other words, it's minuscule and very changing depending on the context.